# How to faster htmlunit?

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm using this java code to load page using HtmlUnit

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED) ;
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(false);
webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar");
```

but it takes too many time (about 25 secs) to execute this piece of code! How can I faster it?
Important: I need to enable Javascript because the page is created by javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use same webclient for each link and if you do not need javascript , disable it from getoptions. My code is checking each link between  0ms-350ms